# Using another start point for AutoCompleTextView droplist

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, autocomplete

Using another start point for AutoCompleTextView droplist

I'm trying to implement an autoCompleteTextView to my app but, while the functioning is done, I'm having problems with the aesthetics of it.

As you may know, the dropdown suggestions for ACTV have their origin at the line underneath the textview, like this:

[image]

I want to make it so the dropdown list has it's origin at the bottom of the white bar around the ACTV, like this:

[image]

How can I do this?, I tried with `android:dropDownVerticalOffset` and `android:dropDownAnchor` since they sounded like they did this but I didn't notice any difference using them.

Comment: `dropDownVerticalOffset` should get the job done, are you sure you noticed no changes?

Comment: OMG I'm so dumb hahah... don't know what I did wrong the first time. Thanks :)